# Small shifts to determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $M$ be some square matrix. Take some column in $M$ and add a vector $\epsilon v$ to it where $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small. Replace this the column in $M$ with this new column vector, call this matrix $M_\epsilon(v)$. I'm interested in how the determinant changes under this operation.
Namely, under what conditions do we have:
$$det(M_\epsilon(v) ) > det(M)$$
as $\epsilon$ tends to $0$.

Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: Imagine you knew the determinant was differentiable as a function of its columns. Could you then express this question in terms of the directional derivative of the determinant? (So this question reduces to the nature of the directional derivative of the determinant). Your hint is that the statement "the determinant increases along a direction $v$"  has to do with "the directional derivative in the direction $v$".

Comment: Determinants are *linear* in each column, so $\det (M_\epsilon(v)) = \det (M) + \epsilon \det (M')$ where $M'$ is the matrix $M$ with the $k$th column replaced by $v$. – In particular, such an estimate never holds if $\epsilon$ can take both positive and negative values.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is a linear function of each column. If $\epsilon v$ is added to the $k^\text{th}$ column of $M$ then
$$
\det (M_\epsilon(v)) = \det (M) + \epsilon \det (M')
$$
where $M'$ is the matrix $M$ with the $k^\text{th}$ column replaces by $v$. In particular,
$$
 \det (M_\epsilon(v)) > \det (M)
$$
cannot hold for all (or all sufficiently small) $\epsilon$ if  $\epsilon$ can take both positive and negative values.

With the additional restriction  $\epsilon > 0$ the desired estimate holds exactly if $\det(M') > 0$.